# How do I run a simple Powershell command from my C# project in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, powershell

I have a simple one line Powershell command which unblocks all dlls in a specific folder. I want to run this command from my C# `main()` method in VS 2015.

I have tried using `Runspace` but VS is not recognizing it.

How can I do this ? Any extensions that I might have to install ?

Comment: Are you not able to use `Process.Start`?

Comment: Not aware of it as I am a beginner at c#. Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: Check my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the followng, `Process.Start` should do as you need.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Path/To/Powershell/Script.ps1");
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, I love the question. I'm a serious PowerShell fan and love to figure out something new about PowerShell almost every day.

Now, for the answer.

Here's what I'm going to do. First, I'm going to open up PowerShell, without making the window show up. Then, I'm going to run the Get-Process command, since it provides some good info. Finally, I'm going to print the results to a screen, then wait for the user to press any key to verify that they saw the response. (If you want it in a string, look into StringBuilder.) This will basically do what you asked; run a single, simple command, and get the output.

Here's the code.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace powershellrun {
    public class program {
        public static void Main(string[] args) {
            //Open up PowerShell with no window
            Process ps = new Process();
            ProcessStartInfo psinfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            psinfo.FileName = "powershell.exe";
            psinfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            psinfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            psinfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            psinfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            ps.StartInfo = psinfo;
            ps.Start();
            //Done with that.

            //Run the command.
            ps.StandardInput.WriteLine("Get-Process");
            ps.StandardInput.Flush();
            ps.StandardInput.Close();
            ps.WaitForExit();
            //Done running it.

            //Write it to the console.
            Console.WriteLine(ps.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
            //Done with everything.

            //Wait for the user to press any key.
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

This should do the job for you.